# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-security

after building spring app, I have this problem:

```
  .../WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
```

My pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <!--<springsecurity.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>-->
</properties>


<dependencies>


    <!--spring security web and config-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

SecurityConfig class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john").password("secret123").roles("EMPLOYEE");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mary").password("secret123").roles("MANAGER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("susan").password("secret123").roles("ADMIN");

    }

}
```

Inizializer:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
```

}

It seems that it can't find jar file after build. I tried adding it to artifacts in Project Structure in IntelliJ Idea, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you building using Maven or Intellij?

Comment: I'm building using maven

Comment: Does the error happen if you use maven on the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to use maven command line in this project. It happens after deploying it using tomcat.

Comment: Double check that needed classes are on application classpath when you run it in container (if container does not provide the library, make sure it is included in the artifact (in artifact `WEB-INF/lib` folder) which you deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: How to add artifact]

Go to Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Click green '+' button -> and all Spring Security libaries

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as of October 2018, if you are using Java 10, you'll encounter issues with the latest spring-security-config Maven dependency. The workaround is to download the  **spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar** [from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/5.0.6.RELEASE). Add the jar to your Classpath and that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Actually in my case springdoc-openapi-ui dependency caused this error. After removing it, my application is working fine. If you have it in pom.xml try new versions or remove it.